# Is there any way to find out the deeplink of a specific page of pubg Mobile

Tags: react-native, mobile-development, deeplink

I need to find out the deeplink of create room page of pubg mobile.
Like the app opens to the create room page when clicked on a button.

Comment: do you want  to make deepLink to your reactNative app?

Comment: No i need a deeplink of Pubg mobile app actually the create room page of pubgmobile app. so our app opens the pubg mobile create room page through a deeplink

Answer (score 0):

Try this Library

> "Easily deep link to other apps in React Native. If the app isn't installed on the user's phone, open the App Store or Play Store link instead."

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link

```
npm i -S react-native-app-link


import AppLink from 'react-native-app-link';

AppLink.maybeOpenURL(url, { appName, appStoreId, appStoreLocale, playStoreId }).then(() => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});

AppLink.openInStore({ appName, appStoreId, appStoreLocale, playStoreId }).then(() => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: I need the deeplink i know how to open the deeplink via this library :)